# In Spyder, is it possible to avoid "SyntaxError: 'return' outside function" when running a cell with a return statement

Tags: python, spyder

In the [Spyder](https://www.spyder-ide.org/) (v.5.4.2) IDE, let:

```py
import modules
# %%
def func(**args):
# %% Spyder cell N
    do stuff
    if not var:
        return # <-- this line causes the error in Spyder when running the current cell
# %%
    else:
        do other stuff
        retval = something
# %%
    return something
```

When I run the Spyder cell N, it says: `SyntaxError: 'return' outside function`.

Is there a way to avoid that so that I can run this particular cell without having to comment the `return` statement in the middle of the function?

Maybe a trick to tell Spyder not to interpret this line, for example as the `# noqa` comment for some linters?

Comment: I think that you must put the whole function into a cell, not just a section

Comment: The "Spyder cells" are just like cells in Jupyter IPython notebook, or code blocks in interactive python shell. You cannot run "part of a function" in this way. Why would you want to do this?

Comment: Maybe you can use debug breakpoints instead